# Redirecting Jekyll-site users depending on the browser language

Tags: jekyll

I want to add localization to my Jekyll site. [This plugin](https://github.com/Anthony-Gaudino/jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin) seems to work. In short - it creates subfolders for all languages which you can access after like `home/yourLang1; home/yourLang2;` with default language always set to plugin's default (the first language in a set).

How can I add redirection for the first time to the browsers preferred language? Is there a mechanism to do this via Jekyll? I found some plugins for redirect like [this](https://github.com/tsmango/jekyll_alias_generator) or [this](https://github.com/nquinlan/jekyll-pageless-redirects), but it doesn't seem what I need.

Answer (score 0):

If your webserver is a apache server you can get that done like this. I assume you have a [.htaccess](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html) file in your web root directory. Add a content handler:

```
# Serve alternate contents (Apache 2.x)
AddHandler type-map .var
# For older versions of Apache use
# AddType application/x-type-map var
DirectoryIndex index.var
```

Now, put a `index.var`-file in your web root directory:

```
URI: index; vary="type,language"

URI: english.html
Content-type: text/html; qs=1.0
Content-language: en

URI: french.html
Content-type: text/html; qs=0.8
Content-language: fr

URI: german.html
Content-type: text/html; qs=0.9
Content-language: de
```

Now your content in `english.html` or `french.html`, ... will be served based on the browsers language when you navigate to your websites url.

This way i have done this for my site and it works pretty well (i did not use a plugin, but coded everything with includes, language data-files and some liquid - even taking care of seo friendly [hreflang tags](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en)).
But, i guess, you could also think of some javascript to redirect to the users language.
Hope this helps!

Comment: I have a static site

Comment: Me too... i use Jekyll for all my sites as well. But "static", in my opinion, does not forbid to use javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Correcting the answer of astark which did not work for me:

The same in the `.htaccess` file:

```
AddHandler type-map .var
DirectoryIndex index.var
```

index.var:

```
URI: index

URI: english.html
Content-type: text/html
Content-language: en

URI: french.html
Content-type: text/html
Content-language: fr

URI: german.html
Content-type: text/html
Content-language: de
```

I just stumbled upon the previous answer and got it to work with these changes. Here some clarifications:

The `qs` are used to specify the quality of the resource to select. E.g. if the browser requests a photograph and a jpeg file would usually be of higher quality than an ascii art of the same thing. For selecting a language specifying this does not make sense and it actually breaks the mechanism, so that english was always selected for me. Have a look at the [apache documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/content-negotiation.html#type-map) for more in-depth explanation.

I do not know what astark was intending to use them for.

A little more explanation about the mechanism: The `index.var` file is now like a dynamic link on the server that, depending on the browsers preferences, points to the file that should be served. By pointing the `DirectoryIndex` to that file the content served with '/' becomes the same content that would be served with '/index.var'.

The lines in the `.var` file are in the same format as the header-lines a browser sends. The first line is only there by convention and can be omitted. The forwarding is based on the filename of the `.var` file.

Hope that saves others some time, that I had to use to investigate.